# DevExpress RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit Search filter

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, devexpress

İ have a grid . There is a RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit in the grid column stock_code. This lookupedit listing all products and when user keypress filtering products.
 [image]

I want the change filter type. Example when i wrote "AB" in search textbox , grid must list just "ABSOLUT".  So grid will filter this "AB%"

When I wrote "%AB" grid will be list all "AB" results in Products name.

How can i do this can anyone help me ?

Comment: you can make Stock Code column editing type to standard and autocomplete mode to absolute.

Comment: i dont understand can you explain me how to do this ?

Comment: You can use RepositoryGridLookupEdit instead of RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit and you should read this. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q21111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit.PopupFilterMode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsPopupFilterModeEnumtopic) property specifies how dropdown rows are filtered - using the `Contains` or `StartsWith` filter. By default, this property is set to PopupFilterMode.Default, which is equivalent to the `Contains` filter. Thus, just set this property to `PopupFilterMode.StartsWith`.

Comment: Its work fine thanks your help. But i want when i write "%AB" grid filtering the PopupFilterMode.Contain, and i write "AB" filtermode change the PopupFilterMode.StartsWith. Can I do this in runtime ?

Comment: @cptc With this question I suggest you contact official DevExpress Support [directly](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) to get guaranteed, official and fast assistance.

Comment: I asked in devexpress forum before but not answered yet. Thanks for repyly again @DimitryG